# Jquery animation img hover and click

Tags: jquery, html

I need your help to combine 2 animations. I have already checked if i can find an answer on the site and i'm still looking for an answer. This is why i'm posting.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$('.bloc-search').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $(this).find('.search').attr('src', function(i, val) {
        return val.replace('-blue.png','-blanc.png');
    });
});
```

It works almost perfectly. Why almost ? Because i want a "clic out" function. In fact, when the user clic on the image this one is changing well but when i'm clicking again i want that it comes back to the original one.

Like the search button on this website : http://www.sony.fr/

Sorry for my english i'm not bilingual ;-)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Here you can find example how manipulating with elements attribute you can perform different behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/weev85hp/
Actually it's answer on your question, but i'm not exactly sure that result match your expectations. `click` to the element assume that mouse is over it what means that `mouseover` change element style and then same binding on `click` change it back. If you expect different behaviour you have to separate these actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case i have no css, only html and jQuery. It's just a switch of two images. Is it possible to do that without a css class or not ? I know i have to separate but i kdon't know how i can do that. Everything works fine until i click again on the image. I want that it comes back to the original one.